# Cannot get value to return

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the ticket to display correctly and every time it just displays '$1'. Am I not returning the value correctly? I can't figure this out.

```
from random import randrange


def main():
    exceeded_speed = 1
    ticket_cost = '$1'
    speed_limit = 50
    vehicle_speed = 1

    get_limit(speed_limit)

    get_speed(vehicle_speed, speed_limit)
    
    ticket_cost = ticket_calculator(speed_limit, vehicle_speed, exceeded_speed, ticket_cost)

    print('Exceeded speed limit by', ticket_cost, 'fine.')


def get_limit(limit):
        limit = int(input('Please Enter the speed limit: '))
        while limit >= 70 or limit <= 20:
            print('ERROR: Speed limit must be between 20 and 70')
            limit = int(input('Please Enter the speed limit: '))
    
        return limit


def get_speed(speed, limit):
    speed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle speed: "))
    while speed >= 200 or speed <= limit:
        print('ERROR: Vehicle speed must be between 71 and 199')
        speed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle speed: "))
    return speed, limit


def ticket_calculator(limit, speed, exceeded, cost):
    exceeded = speed - limit

    if exceeded in range (1,11):
        cost = '1-10 MPH. $50'
        exceeded = ''
    elif exceeded in range (11,16):
        cost = '11-15 MPH. $75'
    elif exceeded in range (16,21):
        cost = '16-20 MPH. $150'
    elif exceeded >= 21:
        cost = '21+ MPH. $300' 

    return cost

main()
```

Comment: You're not assigning the results of the functions to your variables. E.g. `speed_limit = get_limit(speed_limit)`

Comment: Also, the `get_limit()` function never uses its parameter, it gets the limit from the user. Why is it a parameter? I think you need to review a tutorial on functions.

Comment: Hi OP! First of all, welcome to the community. Your problem is an easy fix, but you should study more about functions: what are function parameters / arguments? what are function return values? You are not writing your functions correctly because of the misunderstandings of these concepts.

Comment: It looks like you expect the parameters you passed to be modified inside the function. Python doesn't work that way for immutable types, or if you reassign a variable that points to a mutable type.

Comment: @tianz yes I know. I am a student. I am also on a time budget. Could you please add suggestions to my code directly? that is the best way to help.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you are thinking that this:

```
def get_limit(limit):
    ...
    return limit
```

will return the value in the parameter that was passed.  That's not true.  Arguments always go IN.  What you need is:

```
speed_limit = get_limit()
vehicle_speed = get_speed(speed_limit)
```

And then modify the function headers accordingly:

```
def get_limit():
    ...
def get_speed(limit):
    ...
```

#### Followup

You had `get_speed` returning a tuple.  It only needs to return the vehicle speed.  This works:

```
def main():
    speed_limit = get_limit()
    vehicle_speed = get_speed(speed_limit)
    ticket_cost = ticket_calculator(speed_limit, vehicle_speed)
    print('Exceeded speed limit by', ticket_cost, 'fine.')

def get_limit():
        limit = int(input('Please Enter the speed limit: '))
        while limit >= 70 or limit <= 20:
            print('ERROR: Speed limit must be between 20 and 70')
            limit = int(input('Please Enter the speed limit: '))
        return limit

def get_speed(limit):
    speed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle speed: "))
    while speed >= 200 or speed <= limit:
        print('ERROR: Vehicle speed must be between 71 and 199')
        speed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle speed: "))
    return speed

def ticket_calculator(limit, speed):
    exceeded = speed - limit

    if exceeded in range (1,11):
        cost = '1-10 MPH. $50'
        exceeded = ''
    elif exceeded in range (11,16):
        cost = '11-15 MPH. $75'
    elif exceeded in range (16,21):
        cost = '16-20 MPH. $150'
    elif exceeded >= 21:
        cost = '21+ MPH. $300' 

    return cost

main()
```

Simpler is:

```
def ticket_calculator(limit, speed):
    exceeded = speed - limit

    if exceeded >= 21:
        cost = '21+ MPH. $300' 
    elif exceeded >= 16:
        cost = '16-20 MPH. $150'
    elif exceeded >= 11:
        cost = '11-15 MPH. $75'
    elif exceeded >= 1:
        cost = '1-10 MPH. $50'
    else:
        cost = "N/A"

    return cost
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
Please Enter the speed limit: 50
Please enter the vehicle speed: 150
Exceeded speed limit by 21+ MPH. $300 fine.
```

Comment: okay i fixed that. I'm still getting the problem where it is returning the initial value of '$1' instead of the correct value from the ticket_calculator function.

Comment: You'll have to give us your test data.  If none of the `if` clauses match, you will return the input value.

Comment: uhhh ive been using 50 and 150 respectively. because 150 >= 21 it should return "21+ MPH. $300"

Comment: im still getting the same probkem where $1 is displayed. THATS the problem im trying to fix.

Comment: The code I put in the "Followup" section works.  I proved that before I posted it.  It CAN'T display "$1", because that constant is not in the program anywhere.

Comment: I see. I removed the constants. I suppose those were the problem? I'm not sure why exactly but it works so. Thanks for the help. Really. Your were the only person that didn't tell me to just "go study functions". I learn by doing. I appreciate it,

Comment: It's a difficult line when helping with homework.  We don't want to DO the homework, but in this case I think you had a fundamental misunderstanding, and seeing an example helps.